# Manipulate files from a POST to create a model with django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am using the Django REST Framework to build an API. Currently I am using a `ViewSet` to handle all the actions for a specific model like this:

```
class StAreaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):`
    queryset = StArea.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StAreaSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwner,)
```

I have some data to populate some attributes of the `StArea` object that I upload in a file, a file that I can access in the `request.FILES` dict.

Where can I manipulate the file to get the data I need to create the model?
Should I override the `.create()` method on the `ViewArea`? if so how can I pass
all that information to the `__init__` method on my model?